# No picture/sound on external screen on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde, hdmi

Running kubuntu 18.04, external screen (Toshiba TV) connected through HDMI cable. Ubuntu recognizes external output, acts accordingly, but does not display picture on the external screen (laptop screen works okay).

Output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected primary 1366x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      59.64*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32
   512x384       60.00
   512x288       60.00    59.92
   480x270       59.63    59.82
   400x300       60.32    56.34
   432x243       59.92    59.57
   320x240       60.05
   360x202       59.51    59.13
   320x180       59.84    59.32
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 398mm
   1920x1080     50.00 +  60.00*   59.94
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94
   1280x1024     60.02
   1360x768      60.02
   1280x768      59.87    59.99
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25
   720x576       50.00
   720x576i      50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   720x480i      60.00    59.94
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Output of `sudo lshw -C video`:

```
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 18
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:30 memory:fa400000-fa7fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f080(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
```

`disper -l` segfaults immediately.

Output of `lspci | grep -i vga`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
```